# Ошибка "cannot infer type arguments" при создании ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

Есть две идентичные строки с `new ArrayAdapter<>`. Но лишь вторая выдает ошибку *"cannot infer type arguments"*.

```
// Создаем необходимые элементы интерфейса 
// и глобальные переменные:
private TextView info;
private ListView listCategories;
private ListView listTests;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterCategories;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterTests;

// создаем массив со списком категорий:
ArrayList<String> titleCategories = categories[1];
// Находим список, создаем адаптер и присваиваем адаптер списку:
listCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategories);
// В этой строке все в порядке:
mAdapterCategories = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleCategories);
listCategories.setAdapter(mAdapterCategories);
// Устанавливаем слушатель:
listCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
        selectedCategory = (String) textView.getText();
        // отдаем серверу id выбранной категории, 
        // в ответ получаем массив тестов этой категории
        ArrayList[] tests = server.getTestsByCategory(idCategory.get(position));
        // Из полученного массива выделяем массив с названиями тестов,
        // создаем адаптер, и выводим в ListView:
        ArrayList<String> titleTests = tests[0];
        listTests = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTests);
        // В следующей строке - ошибка 
        mAdapterTests = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleTests);
        listTests.setAdapter(mAdapterTests);
```

Нашел подобную ошибку здесь, но не пойму: какие действия мне нужно предпринять, чтоб всё стало работать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

во втором случае написать:

```
mAdapterTests = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleTests);
```

Ну или вместе `MainActivity` как у тебя класс activity называется.
Просто внутри `OnItemClickListener` просто this ссылается собственно на сам этот listener.

Comment: точно! Я это упустил из вида)